# How to use getOrElseUpdate in scala.collection.mutable.HashMap?

Tags: scala, dictionary, hashmap

The example code counts each word's occurrences in given input file:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val counts = new scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]
    val in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))

    while (in.hasNext()) {
      val s: String = in.next()
      counts(s) = counts.getOrElse(s, 0) + 1 // Here!
    }

    print(counts)
  }
}
```

Can the highlighted with comment line be rewritten using the `getOrElseUpdate` method?

P.S. I am only at the 4th part of the "Scala for the impatient", so please don't teach me now about functional Scala which, I am sure, can be more beautiful here.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the intention of the code?  To count the number of characters in the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [doc](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashMap) you'll see the next:

> If given key is already in this map, **returns associated value**.
>   Otherwise, computes value from given expression op, stores with key in
>   map and returns that value.

, but you need to modify map anyway, so `getOrElseUpdate` is useless here.

You can define `default` value, which will return if **key** doesn't exist. And use it the next way:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val counts = HashMap[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)
    val in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"))

    while (in.hasNext()) {
      val s: String = in.next()
      counts(s) += 1
    }

    print(counts)
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice method, but u have to put parenthesis after `val counts = HashMap[String, Int]().withDefaultValue(0)`